# Modify custom BaseAdaptor position attribute in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an array of 30 items which i need to display in a listview. However, per my layout I'll be displaying 2 items side by side in one row of listview.

Since there are now going to be only 15 rows to display (30/2), how do i modify the position attribute of Adapter such that i see only 15 rows.

I tried doing position++, in getView and also modify getCount() to return 15, but that does not work either.

Comment: This sounds a lot more complex than using a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) with two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than do it this way, a better method may be to simply count two items as one row.  The `getView()` method returns a View that is a representation of each item returned by `getItem()`.  In your case, each item contains two elements.  So just put the logic in that would retrieve two elements at a time.  May be easier to encapsulate them in a class like for example:

```
ArrayList<Row> mItems = new ArrayList<Row>();

private class Row {
  Object obj1;
  Object obj2;
}

public void addItem(Object obj) {
  Row useRow;
  if(mItems.isEmpty()) {
     useRow = new Row();
  } else {
     useRow = mItems.get(mItems.size() - 1);
     if(useRow.obj2 != null) {
        useRow = new Row();
     }
  }

  if(useRow.obj1 == null) {
     useRow.obj1 = obj;
  } else {
     useRow.obj2 = obj;
  } 

  mItems.add(useRow);
}
```

In this case, your BaseAdapter is backed by a List of `Row` objects.  Each `Row` object contains two of your elements.  Every time you add an element, you add it to the first, then to the second, else you create a new `Row` object and add it.

EDIT:

In order to have clickability, you'll have to implement an OnClickListener to each item's View.  Something like this may work:

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
   public void onItemClick(Object obj);
}

private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener listener) {
   mClickListener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
  return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
   return false;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewGroup root;
   if(convertView == null) {
      root = buildRootView();
      View item1View = buildFirstView();
      View item2View = buildSecondView();
      ...
      item1View.setOnClickListener(mItemListener);
      item2View.setOnClickListener(mItemListener);
      ...
      // Put both Views in your top level root view if they are not there already
   }

   Row row = getItem(position);
   item1View.setTag(row.obj1);
   item2View.setTag(row.obj2);
}

private View.OnClickListener mItemListener = new View.OnClickListener {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Object obj = (Object) v.getTag();
      if(mClickListener != null) {
          mClickListener.onItemClick(obj);
      }
   }
}
```

So basically, you disable the clicking by overriding "areAllItemsEnabled()" and "isEnabled()" to return "false".  Then, the click listener in the adapter will activate each time the user clicks on a row.  Since you put the `Object` of the row in the `View`'s tag, you can retrieve it on click.  It will be swapped to a new `Object` even when the `ListView` recycles because it calls `getView()` each time.  Then create an object that inherits from the click interface to retrieve the object and do whatever you need.

Comment: So i did this and got everything working. Could you provide some inputs on how to handle click event on each item.

Comment: That adds difficulty, but you can't use the ListView's `onItem...` methods.  You have to disable that and implement the clicking yourself.  I'll edit with a possible suggestion though it really depends on your app.